# using axios for post call in parallel

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, async-await, axios

I’ve this axios request which is running **ok** I got http 200

```
import {AxiosResponse} from "axios";

const axios = require('axios').default;
const qs = require('qs');

//First query 
axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: 'https://oauth2.-arch.mand.com/oauth2/token',
    data: qs.stringify({'grant_type': 'client_credentials'}, {'scope': 'run:crud'}),
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Basic NTgwNjgtMDhhZTczOGNl',
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    }
}).then(function (response: AxiosResponse) {

    console.log(response.data);
}).catch(function (error: any) {
    console.log("Error: " + error);
});
```

**//Second query  (the only different is the scope )**

```
axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: 'https://oauth2.-arch.mand.com/oauth2/token',
    data: qs.stringify({'grant_type': 'client_credentials'}, {'scope': ‘exe:crud’}),
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Basic NTgwNjgtMDhhZTczOGNl',
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    }
}).then(function (response: AxiosResponse) {

    console.log(response.data);
}).catch(function (error: any) {
    console.log("Error: " + error);
});
```

Now I want to run two request **in parallel** and get the results which is `response.data` (the data I sent to the request / headers etc)

I’ve tried with but the response I got is like the request , I don’t get the tokens/data? Any idea 
**How can I use this two request in parallel** ?

```
axios.all([{
    method: 'post',
    url: 'https://oauth2.-arch.mand.com/oauth2/token',
    data: qs.stringify({'grant_type': 'client_credentials'}, {'scope': 'run:crud'}),
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': 'Basic NTgwNjgtMDhhZTczOGNl',
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        }
    },

        {
            method: 'post',
            url: 'https://oauth2.-arch.mand.com/oauth2/token',
            data: qs.stringify({'grant_type': 'client_credentials'}, {'scope': 'exe:crud'}),
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': 'Basic NTgwNjgtMDhhZTczOGNl',
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            }
        }]).then(axios.spread((...responses: AxiosResponse[]) =>{

        const aToken = responses[0];
        const bToken = responses[1];
    }).catch(function (error: any) {
        console.log("Error: " + error);
    });
```

If there is a better way , please let me know

Btw, if I run this two post request separated everything is working fine

Comment: what if you change the syntax a little bit ? `.then(axios.spread((aToken, bToken) => {
  // output of req.
  console.log('aToken', aToken, 'bToken', bToken)})`

Comment: @CristianGabor - thanks I've tried it and im getting the same results, which is the two request object which I put in the `axios.all`  . I can see in debug the url the method etc, I want to get the token...any idea?

Comment: @CristianGabor - thanks I've tried it and im getting the same results, which is the two request object which I put in the `axios.all`  . I can see in debug the url the method etc, I want to get the token...any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide promises to the `axios.all` not their config objects.

```js
axios.all([
    axios({
      method: 'post',
      url: 'https://oauth2.-arch.mand.com/oauth2/token',
      data: qs.stringify({
        'grant_type': 'client_credentials'
      }, {
        'scope': 'run:crud'
      }),
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Basic NTgwNjgtMDhhZTczOGNl',
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      }
    }),
    axios({
      method: 'post',
      url: 'https://oauth2.-arch.mand.com/oauth2/token',
      data: qs.stringify({
        'grant_type': 'client_credentials'
      }, {
        'scope': 'exe:crud'
      }),
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Basic NTgwNjgtMDhhZTczOGNl',
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      }
    })
  ]).then(axios.spread((...responses: AxiosResponse[]) => {
      const aToken = responses[0];
      const bToken = responses[1];
    }).catch(function(error: any) {
      console.log("Error: " + error);
    });
```

---

Keep in mind though that the `axios.all` and `axios.spread` are [deprecated](https://github.com/axios/axios#concurrency-deprecated).

Use [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) directly

Comment: Thanks a lot, it will be great if you can provide an example how should I change the code  without the deprecation. thanks